# Filling a matrix in R with means from columns of imported tables using loops

Tags: r, loops

If I read three tables into R and rename them:

```
y1<-read.csv(file="table1",header=T)
y2<-read.csv(file="table2",header=T)
y3<-read.csv(file="table3",header=T)
```

and I know each table has 14 columns and 10 rows.

Then I want to take the mean of column 1 in table1 and drop it into a matrix at position [1,1], the mean of column 2 in table1 and drop it into the same matrix at position [1,2], etc, until I have the bottom right of the matrix [3,14] filled with the mean of the 14th column in table 3.

I started by creating a blank matrix

```
>m=data.frame(matrix(0,3,14))
```

and also a vector containing the tables

```
z<-(y1,y2,y3)
```

Then I decided to use a loop within a loop looking something like:

```
>for(i in z){
            for(j in 1:14){
                           m[i,j]<-mean(i[,j])
                           }}
```

It returned an error, and i can see in a basic way why it can't be right. However, I am struggling to come up with a way to get the values inputted into the matrix. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
t(sapply(paste0("table", 1:3), function(x) colMeans(read.csv(file=x,header=T))))
```

Comment: Perhaps I should have thought about this fully before I typed out the question. I tried to simplify it to make it easier to read/understand. Basically, all of my file names are not as simple as table1, table2. They are in fact country names. Further, i actually want to perform a test on each column of each table (rather than the means) using the >chisq.benftest(table1[,1]) command from the BenfordTests package in R.